# Is just me or we are in much extents, powerless when debugging/diagnosing Windows?

Tags: windows, debug, diagnostic, maintenance

Is there a vast logging system? Like what we see in `/var/log` on Linux? Is there some place where I can search for "error IDs" or things like this and somewhere that documents so I can study it?

Many times I've felt powerless when wireless simply did not connect and the system pretend nothing happened, or even "automated diagnose" don't have a clue.

Comment: try Win+R and type `eventvwr`. you can also find crash reports

Comment: I appreciate explanations about downvoting...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I would advise you lose the attitude. Yes, it's just you. Yes, of course there's a vast logging system. No it's not the same as Linux. It appears you've done no research whatsoever and are just whining because your Linux skills don't directly translate into Windows.

Comment: I'm sorry, sure, I'm having a difficult time even mapping the question, I asked this because a clear search on google like "how to diagnose problems on Window", did not mapped well to "how to diagnose problems on linux". The search pointed me to `system monitors`, `register cleaners` `spy/virus cleaner`, `defragmentation`, `disk cleaners`, etc instead of pointing **good ways to manually clean and correct things yourself, understanding what is happening behind**, I want to understand it, not only get a blind solution, but I nearly constantly get a "put code on google and see if it help".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Viewer is your friend. Start with the System and Application logs. You can also filter for errors and warnings.

[image: Event Viewer]

Also Device Manager is great for diagnosing hardware and driver problems.

[image: Device Manager]

You can find both by right-clicking on the Start Button in Windows 10

Comment: Thanks, next time I face problems I will look event viewer too, anyway, this is pretty much the maximum we can get of information? Device Manager failed me some times, just showing an `device working properly` with no relevant events on it

Comment: It's not the maximum you can get of information. Windows is a completely different world compared to Linux. There are lots of powerful tools, you can set logging for hundreds of events, but these are just a starting point. It's really a completely different mindset. You can try researching PowerShell if you're used to command line tools. There are log files and memory dumps and diagnostic tools, etc. but they can be very specific to the issue at hand. Welcome to Windows!

Comment: No problem with the different mindset,  I just really wanted a guidance to "equivalents", as it did not appear to be a common subject and all place I look too, people talk about "inevitable formating of system". And I want to have faith there is more someone from TI could teach itself to do when things go wrong on Windows... Thanks!